# Django 1.4 "LOGGING" variable in settings.py seems to be ignored

Tags: python, django, logging, django-1.4

I've got a module I want to log in Django that looks something like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def foo():
    #this is a test of logging
    logger.info("info foo")
    logger.warning("warn foo")
    logger.error("error foo")
```

My LOGGING in settings.py is set to the following:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
            },
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['null', 'console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'INFO',
            },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
            },
    }
}
```

The output when I run a view calling foo is as follows:

```
WARNING:root:warn foo
ERROR:root:error foo
```

I would've expected the info log as well, but ok, let's try again but this time with every 'level' parameter in LOGGING set to 'INFO':

```
WARNING:root:warn foo
ERROR:root:error foo
```

OK... well how about setting everything to 'ERROR'?:

```
WARNING:root:warn foo
ERROR:root:error foo
```

LOGGING commented out?

```
WARNING:root:warn foo
ERROR:root:error foo
```

I've set DEBUG = False and even bothered to manually set

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'django.utils.log.dictConfig'
```

Does anyone have any other ideas? I don't understand why Django is ignoring my LOGGING setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, typing it up on stack overflow lead me to realize my mistake.

Rather than calling

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I needed to call the desired logger specifically:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('django')
```

This has solved the problem.