# Do Django loggers have a universal parent?

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging

I want to [keep the convention of naming loggers for their module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#naming-loggers) with `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, but have a single logger that captures them all.

Is that possible, and what should the logger's name be?

(I do not want to [switch everything to `logger = logging.getLogger('django')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11971555/236081))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, the default logger is the root logger `''`, you can get it via:

- [`logging.getLogger()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger)
- [`logging.getLogger('')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger)

Note the different type:

```
>>> logging.getLogger('')
<logging.RootLogger object at 0x7f0b9521ec18>
```

in Django you can add handlers to the root logger easily:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['system_log', 'debug_log', 'sentry'],
        },
    },
}
```

If you attach a handler to the root logger, it will see ALL the logs. This is not always wanted. So if you attach some handlers to a more specialised logger, you can then set the other one to [`propagate=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) so that the message doesn't reach the root logger.

```
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['system_log', 'debug_log', 'sentry'],
        },
        'django': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['another_handler_just_for_django'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
   },
```